# How do I fix the object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My player was destroyed but unity provides an error message of "The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object." I do not know how to fix the code and need help!

Here is the code to my CameraMovement

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() => transform.position = new Vector3(target.transform.position.x, target.transform.position.y, transform.position.z);



}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your update method to `if(target != null)` then update

Comment: well you seem to destroy the `target` somewhere ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the Update method is called every frame regardless if the object is destroyed or not. Therefore if the target object (which seems to be the player) is destroyed the `CameraController` is still trying to access it and trying to align itself with the player.

---

### Solution

```cs
void Update() {
    if (target != null) {
        transform.position = new Vector3(target.transform.position.x, target.transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

This code ensures that if the player (target) is destroyed, the camera doesn't try to access it.

Comment: Btw why not simply `transform.position = target.position;` ..?

Answer (score 0):

**WHY DO YOU GET ERROR**

Because you are destroying the player; camera can not follow anyone anymore. Even tho it tries to do what you have told to, it cant reach for the target.

**You can do:**
[try-catch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.LogException.html) to not get any error.
You can try to ensure it by non-null code. You can check the answer that Obscure021 gave.